# How to ListView.setSelection(int) when ListView is contained in a ScrollView?

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I have a ListView which can't be scrolled due to I'm setting its Height programmatically.

I have aprox. 50 elements in this ListView, each element is bigger than the screen itself. I'm using a ScrollView to be able to see every element on my ListView. I decided to implement ScrollView -> ListView because at the top of my Fragment I have other Layouts which must be scrolled up/down when I'm trying to see all my List elements.

I have the same information in other fragment in a GridView, when I click in a position, I want to switch to my ListView fragment and "setSelection" to the element I just clicked on my GridView. I've made some tests without the ScrollView and its working fine, but I cant scrolled up/down the others layouts as I wish.

Is there any way to accomplish this? Is there any way to make the setSelection move to the desire position in my ListView, when it is inside a ScrollView?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Using a ListView inside a ScrollView is not recommended, it will not work as the gestures get all messed up. If you just want to be able to scroll really big layouts why don't you just use your ScrollView? why do you need a ListView

Comment: "I have aprox. 50 elements in this ListView, each element is bigger than the screen itself" -- that is scary beyond words.

Comment: BigBen: I'm using a listview because I wanted to use setSelection to move to an specific position in my view, but that doesn't seems to work if it is inside a ScrollView. I know it is not recommended to use a Listview inside a ScrollView, but from the begging I cant see the listview because of the other layouts, that is why I need a ScrollView.

Comment: CommonsWare: I know is scary, but that is what the client asked for.

Comment: I'm trying to solved this by using ScrollViewscrollTo(x,y), but still looking if there is a way to use setSelection in this scenario